# bold arrow in caption

Tags: math-mode, symbols, bold, bm

I need to write in a caption `$\overleftarrow{A}$` and make it bold, but when I compile I get the error

> "illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a."

So to make it compile I use `$\protect\overleftarrow{A}$`, but if I try using `\bm` to make the all part bold I get the same error reported above. Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

With `\boldmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{text \boldmath$\protect\overleftarrow{A}$ }
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: using \boldmath the difference between bold e normal is almost unnoticeable in my text. Is there a reason why?

Comment: actually to be precise using \boldmath$\protect\overleftarrow{A}$ in my caption does not produce a symbol in bold but it compiles. Please help.

Comment: @user160430 How do you compile? With pdflatex or something else? Do you get any errors or warning in your log?

Comment: I compile with pdftexify and yes I receive some warnings.

Comment: @user160430 Can you share the .log file?